# reversal of computer camera image

Tags: camera, computers, thermal-camera

Why do so many embedded cameras in computers, etc., prsent a mirror image?  It means anything with writing on it is backwards.

Why is this desirable?

Comment: a camera doesn't present anything; it's an observer. A display, maybe a saved image show or contain (re)presentations of an image. So, your statement really makes no sense: Some part in your image processing chain decides which is the right direction. In most technical implementations, the image you get is actually not mirrored, so you are most likely looking at a non-representative subset of things that you can do with the data that comes from a camera. There's really nothing to answer here: some software that *you* use is most probably doing or not doing mirroring.

Comment: The face camera is transmitted normal to the recipient and mirrored to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cameras in general are mirrored - all the way back to analog film.

The sensor being placed behind the lens means that the lens creates a mirror image of the world (in front of the lens) on the sensor, and the sensor merely senses the light as it lands on it.

It's more of a convention - in the analog film world, the negative (sensor) was mirrored as well. The positive was created by projecting the negative (shining light through it) onto a final (enlarged) screen print.

This is still actually the case in the projected display setting - so essentially the LCD or DLP inside a projector needs to be mirrored, in order for the image on the screen (again, behind, this time, a projection lens) be correct again.

Now, it's desirable because:

1. the inversion is simple in software, and actually doesn't matter at the intermediate stage, you just need to correct it before final display
2. the historic setup when the viewer was *behind* the camera, makes it more natural

It is challenging with the 'selfie' cameras, where you are essentially staring into the camera, and attempting to view the image from the camera on a screen directly below. Then people prefer to be able to move in the same direction as the image on the screen.

Comment: This is not true from the first paragraph. the lens will produce an upside down, left-to-right  reversed image. Which is overall just a rotation and not a reflection.

Comment: I think the point that I'd like to add here is that just because the projected image on the sensor is upside down, left right mirrored, the data sent to the system isn't: the pixels are simple read out / serialized from the bottom right corner, and the first pixel can then be interpreted by the receiver as the top left pixel, or the bottom right. It really doesn't matter. It's just an interpretation of the data. The data itself hasn't got the attribute "this thing is right in the real world"

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed. This is why I am always getting a bit pissed off when someone is repeating that claim that "in reality" we see an upside-down image, because it is the way the image is displayed on our retina.

Comment: it really only matters what your brain sees.  So, yes, the image is right side up and mirrored left to right.  If you wore glasses that turned everything upside down, within a few weeks what you will see will become "right side up".  So all the debate about what the sensor sees. etc., is sort of irrelevant.  What the end result is, is that we see it as backwards.

Answer (score 1):

So when you look at yourself it appears like a mirror, this is how we are used to looking at ourselves. Without the reversal, when you moved your head to the right, the image would move to the left and it could be disorienting.

Some software has an option to remove the reversal.